# SharePoint - Add multiple Users quickly

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have an Excel File that contain names of multiple users (99 users with their name and email), and i want to add all of them in one go in sharepoint, When i click in Members -> Add member : i can only put one user but i want to add multiple users, like a way to automate the process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a semicolon (;) to every cell that is holding the email for every user by using a function: `=concatenate(A1&”;”)`

Then you should be able to copy and paste multiple cells/email-adresses at the same time and have SharePoint map them to the right user-account as semicolon is the separator used for any lookup-data like peoplepicker, metadata and lookup-columns.